# R ggplot geom_bar() label bars (with 'count')

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I have a ggplot like this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=DateDiff, fill=TEAM)) + geom_bar()
```

How can I label the bars with the results from the y axis, when there's no y axis defined? (without altering the df)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear)) + geom_bar()+
  geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-1)
```